# Keep last working day of each month in a dataset

Tags: date, sas, format

I have a large dataset with c 5000 daily returns for a specific variable i.e. swap spread here .

I just want to keep the last working day or day printed in each month for the whole dataset.

Tried the function below but its missing dates;

```
if date~=(intx('month',date,-1)1) then delete;
```

an answer explaining how to obtain the last available day of each month in dataset;

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  where date = intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date,0,'e'),0);
```

Example:

```
data have;
  do date = today()-720 to today();
    amount = int(ranuni(1) * 100);
    output;
  end;
  format date yymmdd10.;
run;

proc print data=have;
  title 'Date is last day of month';
  where date = intnx('month', date, 0, 'e');
  format date weekdate.;
run;

proc print data=have;
  title 'Date is last weekday of month';
  where date = intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date,0,'e'),0);
  format date weekdate.;
run;

proc print data=have;
  title 'Date is last weekday of month and not last day of month';
  where date  = intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date,0,'e'),0)
    and date ^= intnx('month', date, 0, 'e')
  ;
  format date weekdate.;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One other option, because it seems you have stock type data and the calendar is not standard.

Use a sorted data set and a `groupformat` option on your BY statement.

```
proc sort data=have;
by date;
run;

data last_month;
by date groupformat;
format date yymmn6.;
if last.date;
keep date;
run;
```

That will create a list of the last dates per month. And then you can merge that back with your data to get the records of interest.